# Only c# native classes are recognized

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I migrated a silverlight 5 project from vs2013 to 2015 (both professionnal edition).

This is not even a real migration, because there is nothing to change in the code, or configuration, and Visual Studio say nothing when opening the project with 2015 instead of 2013.

The weird thing is, in VS 2015, my classes are not recognized in the code, and so, I cannot use completion.

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the code below, the word `RivoliView` is still black, because it is not recognized like DemView. The consequences are, I cannot use `adresseBDUChild` and access it's properties, while `RivoliView` is in the same namespace and a public page (the same way that DemView 'public partial class), and therefore, should berecognized.

In fact, all the classes that are not **c# native** (by native I mean like `int`, `string` `List<T>`, `Boolean`) are not recognized there, whle it was in studio 2013.

I cannot access properties from my classes, cannot have autocompletion.

What happened?

The project compile perfectly, and work perfectly when running in debug in the browser. It works excalty the same way it was in vs2013. But the problem here seems to come from visual studio.

I tried to get the project directly from Team Foundation server. Nothing.

Tried clean, rebuild, build, deleting .pdb files etc... No errors, but change Nothing. It always run as it should, without probems. Still not recognized.

Is it a vs2015 configuration problem?

The namespaces are well defined, and used in the page. This is weird since the same code recognized this classes in visual studio 2013.

Any idea?

I hope my question contains all useful details that I thinked about. If I forgot, tell me how I can be more specific.

**Edit : still searching, and got no clue. I think I will go back in 2013 if I can't find an answer.**

Now I also tried :

```
EDIT > IntelliSense > Refresh Remote References

removing and re-adding project references, such as Microsoft.CSharp.
```

Adding and removing the project from solution.
Creating new solution and then add the projects.

Thank you.

Comment: "while RivoliView is in the same namespace, and therefore, should berecognized" - namespaces don't have anything to do with access control in C#. What do you mean by this? And what do you mean by "not c# native"?

Comment: @JonSkeet Presumably OP means native c# types (Int32, String, etc.) but I'd hate to assume anything

Comment: @JonSkeet indeed, namespace is not all. But I should add, that they are both public (added a picture of the rivoliView). As BenKnoble said, I indeed meant class like string, int, List<T> etc... Editing my question.

Comment: Have you successfully rebuilt the project?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Yes. I did clean, build, rebuild etc... Always Ok, always run without problems. But I think the weirdest part is that in 2013 it works, and there is no changes in the visual 2015 one. Same namespaces, same using, same directory...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds funny, but you might want to try removing and re-adding project references, such as Microsoft.CSharp.

That can often give VS2015 the kick it needs to re-analyse the project.

Edit:

When I say remove and re-adding, I mean via References under the Solution explorer.

Open references, right click on Microsoft.CSharp, and choose remove.
Add a new reference, go to Framework and find Microsoft.CSharp and add it.

It seems to make a difference for me when I do this manually without using Resharper or Visual Studio to resolve the reference for me.

Comment: It' does not funny at all at this point. Your answer doesn't work but I noticed something : in my classes, I cannot use the "resolve" from visual studio, even if the dll is in the project, while I used to add my using with the resolve button. I think it is linked but I don't know how.

Comment: I meant funny as it's an non obvious way to make Visual studio pick up your classes. Shame it doesn't work though, it's the usual trick I use. Are you doing it in the same way though? I'll update my proper answer.

Comment: Well, I simply removed with right click, then click on add reference. I don't use resharper, and to add the reference in the references, I have to click on references, add reference, then choose between assembly or com.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing it exactly the same as me; sorry it doesn't help you/

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh IntelliSense cache

> EDIT > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache

and/or

> EDIT > IntelliSense > Refresh Remote References

Comment: No, this change nothing (tried on each project individually, the solution and pages).